# Induced map on cohomology is preimage in geometry

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, de-rham-cohomology, poincare-duality

My question is about p. 69 of Bott Tu. I don't understand how the commutative diagram implies that if $\omega$ is the cohomology class on $M$ representing $S$, then $f^*\omega$ represents $f^{-1}(S)$. I'm also not sure what they mean by "representing" a submanifold—is $\omega$ just the Poincaré dual $\eta_S$, or is it something else?

[image]

Comment: Does "orientation preserving" also mean a diffeomorphism here? Or is it only taken to be $f^{*} \omega = \lambda^{2} \omega ', \lambda(x) \neq 0$ without any assumptions on the bijectiveness of f?

If $f$ is a diffeomorphism, or at least if $deg(f)=1$, i believe this claim also follows from:

$\int_{M'} f^{*} \omega \wedge f^{*} \eta_{S} = \int_{M} \omega \wedge \eta_{S} = \int_{S} \omega = \int_{f^{-1} (S)} f^{*} \omega = \int_{M'} f^{*} \omega \wedge \eta_{f^{-1}(S)}$ for all closed $\omega$.


But of course that's not really what you asked.

Comment: @TomAriel Ahh it does imply that $f$ is a diffeomorphism! (I don't know if that's always required, but at least in the book, that's the definition) Thanks :)